# Importing data from Excel to REDCap using API by Python

Tags: python, excel, api, import, redcap

I am new in the Python world but have a reasonable understanding at a basic level. I would appreciate it if someone could share a guide on how to import data from Excel to REDCap using API Python. The data which I have are medical-related like patient name, age, comorbidities, ... etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Approach this in two steps.

1. Use something like [pandas.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to get the data under control of Python.
2. Then use the [PyCap](http://redcap-tools.github.io/PyCap/) package's [`import_records()`](http://redcap-tools.github.io/PyCap/api_reference/records/#redcap.methods.records.Records.import_records) to write the records to the REDCap server.

(In future SO posts, include more details so the code can be more tailored.  I know it's tricky when PHI is involved and a fake dataset must be used on SO.)